# Can I use epoxy resin to fix a metal hook to a uPVC door, to stop it blowing in the wind?

Tags: doors, adhesive

I have a uPVC back door which often blows in the wind. I want to fix a [hook and eye](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stainless-Steel-Heavy-Cabin-Garage/dp/B086DWR5FX) similar to this to the exterior surface so I can leave it open and clip it to the wall.

Will epoxy resin such as Araldite do this job? The door is about 22 sq ft and the max wind speed here is about 25 mph. Using the generic formula at [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Wind-Load#:%7E:text=4-,Calculate%20wind%20pressure.,x%20702%20%3D%2012.5%20psf.) I get a wind load of about 70 pounds.

Say the gluing area of the hook is about 1 sq inch. Will a general-purpose epoxy do the job?

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners, nobody knows where they're going and they may be presumed to be spam or cause people to go look them up. I've translated them back to their full text so they're visible to future readers and, if you look at the edit history, you can see how to do that so you don't have to have a mile-long URL in the middle of your question.

Comment: while you are at it, replace the hook with something that is spring loaded, so that it is able o withstand shock from. the wind and does not break off again

Comment: @jsotola I'm not sure there is an original that has broken off, but I agree 100% that a spring loaded one would be a _great_ idea to reduce the impact load when the wind catches the door.

Comment: thanks for the tip @Freeman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but I suspect it will not be strong enough to hold over the long-term.

I think I'd drill holes in the door and bolt the hook to the frame instead of trying to use adhesive or epoxy.

The best would be bolts through the entire thickness of the door with a washer and nut on the other side.  Next would be some self-tapping screws suitable for plastic (usually wood screws will do the trick here) but you'll have to be very careful to avoid stripping the plastic when tightening.

Comment: I agree with bolts but caution on self tappers (I love them and use them often but on plastics they tend to crack things) . Drilling and tapping may be safer if not enough threads then put some epoxy in between after roughing the plastic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **Loctite Epoxy Marine.**

*Bonding metal, concrete, glass, fiberglass, ceramic, wood and certain rigid plastics. Use for surfaces exposed to water immersion. Ideal for **PVC**, copper, aluminum, brass and galvanized pipes.*

Comment: That is a good epoxy I have used it on my boat, I find it works best if you rough up the plastic / metal it helps to hold my speakers in place.

Comment: While it may be designed to adhere to PVC, the contact patch the OP is talking about may not be big enough to hold against the expected wind loads.

Comment: I think it more likely the epoxy holds and the contact/glue point on the door gives way!

Comment: Valid point! Much like wood failing before the glued joint does...